# Random() method keeps changing final String in Java

Tags: java, function, methods, subroutine

I'm trying to create a rock paper scissors game and teach myself more about subroutines in Java. To  check whether the logic behind it is right, I wrote in two parts in the program where the current hand position of the opposing player is checked. However, it's different every time, even though I assigned it to a final String within a separate method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RockPaperScissors {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String choice = "start";

        System.out.println("Welcome to a friendly game of Rock, Paper, Scissors!");
        System.out.println("Type in 'start' , 'continue' or 'yes' to play the game, and 'quit' or 'no' to quit the game");

        choice = input.nextLine();

        try {
            while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("start") || choice.equalsIgnoreCase("continue") || choice.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {

                System.out.println("Rock, Paper or Scissors?");

                String answer = input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enemy player chose " + set()); // checks current position
                comparison(answer);
                System.out.println("Would you like to continue?");
                choice = input.next();

            }
            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
            System.out.println("Have a wonderful day!");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid player input.");
        }
    }

    static String random() {
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
        String current = null;
        switch (random) {
        case 0:
            current = "Rock";
            break;
        case 1:
            current = "Paper";
            break;
        case 2:
            current = "Scissors";
            break;
        }
        return current;
    }

    static String set() {
        final String a = random();
        return a;
    }

    static void comparison(String filler) {
        String answer = null;
        System.out.println(set()); // checks current position

        if (filler.equalsIgnoreCase(random())) {
            System.out.println("Draw!");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf("You both chose %s ", random());
            System.out.println();
        } else if (filler.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock")) {
            if (set().equals("Scissors"))
                System.out.println("Rock beats Scissors, you win!");
            else
                System.out.println("Paper beats Rock, you lose...");
        } else if (filler.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper")) {
            if (set().equalsIgnoreCase("Rock"))
                System.out.println("Paper beats Rock, you win!");
            else
                System.out.println("Scissors beat Paper, you lose...");
        } else if (filler.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors")) {

            if (set().equalsIgnoreCase("Paper"))
                System.out.println("Scissors beat paper, you lose...");
            else
                System.out.println("Rock beats scissors, you lose...");
        } else
            System.out.println("Unknown player input.");

    }

}
```

Comment: You could use just your random() method, which has the same effect as set(), returning the random String value: Rock, Paper or Scrissors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, every time you call a method it runs again, so the variables and return values in that method change.
 So you have to run the method random once and then use then pass that result where it's needed:

```
//...
String enemy = random();
System.out.println("Enemy player chose " + enemy); //checks current position
comparison(answer, enemy);
//...
static void comparison(String answer, String enemy) {
     //do not call random() or set() in here
     //just use the answer and enemy parameters
}
```

Comment: I was preparing the same answer, yours is probably the closest to the problem solving.

Comment: Thanks, ended up just adding the extra parameter and deleted the set() method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
static String set()
{
    final String a = random();

    return a;
}
```

every time, you call this function a NEW final String a is created. The Variable a is only created locally and dispatched when the method is done, though the system doesnt remember that it has been final

if you want your AI to only once pick, create a final String in the beginning of your main method.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
.
.
final String pick=set();
try
```

Answer (score 1):

A `final` local variable is only unchangeable within the method that it is declared in - and for every invocation it can be different.

You can however use a field for this - the first time, you will initialize the field with a random choice, and on further invocations you will use the value of the field.

This works better if you do not make everything `static`. But to make your current code work, you can do:

```
private static String choice;

static String set()
{
    if (choice == null) {
        choice = random();
    }
    return choice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method set() is wrong. it uses internal variable 'a' which is erased (created new on stack) each time method is called. You need to change variable a to class variable.
Anyway final will just not work here, you need check if variable a is null and only then assign value.